# Is it RESTful to receive the POST Data as raw body?

Tags: api, http, rest

If I offer a POST in my REST API, say like

```
https://api.myservice.com/myresource
```

and I want to accept a complex JSON string/object from within the POST.

Should I

- omit the JSON and map the entire object to the URL (which would be quite uncool)
- add the JSON Data as key => value pairs to the JSON
- am I able to just access the raw body data or wouldn't that be any more restful?

Comment: Can you define a content type for this kind of content?

Comment: What do you mean by: "*add the JSON Data as key => value pairs to the JSON*"? Anyway, I would just accept the JSON content as part of the body of the POST request.

Comment: @Tichodroma: What do you mean? Content-Type is of course application/json; the whole API is build around JSON.

Comment: @Tichodroma - Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/q/477816/274261

Comment: @shredding You are talking about 'a complex JSON string/object'. Is this *only* JSON?

Comment: @Tichodroma: It's a string in the JSON format, so yes only JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `POST` to the URL `https://api.myservice.com/myresource` you would be creating a `myresource` with the details in the `POST` body. The URL generally should contain your resources.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the options you have listed I don't see any impact on any of the REST constraints.  It is more valuable to ask yourself am I violating any of the REST constraints and if so, what benefits am I losing and make your decision on the relative pros and cons.

Achieving "RESTful" status should not be the end goal.  Picking the constraints that are important to your application and applying them should be the goal.